# what is this special kind of character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been following a python 3 book and have been learning to program on my own but the book doesn't explain this particularly:

```
print(end = "%2i" % column)
```

I empirically found out that they replace the value outside with inside, but I'd like to be specific about this. I would have liked to Google it up before resolving here but I don't even know what is it called and are there any other expressions like these what are these called?

Comment: This is a `printf` format string. Although `printf` is a C function, many languages use its format string specification for formatting data.

Comment: What you are asking is in the documentation. [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. First, let's look at the string:

```
'%2i' % column
```

In this string, the `%` indicates that a value can be substituted in that location in the string. The `2` indicates that the substitution will be *at least* 2 characters wide. The `i` indicates that an integer should be passed as the formatting argument. Then, the `% column` part indicates that the integer `column` should be substituted in for `%2i` per the rules described above. Here are some examples:

```
'%2i' % 4  # ' 4'
'%2i' % 12 # '12'
'%3i' % 12 # ' 12'
'%s: %s' % ('a', 'b') # 'a: b'
```

The final example shows that multiple values can be substituted in. All this being said, using `%` for string formatting is not recommended; instead `str.format` is preferred.

```
'{}: {}'.format('a', 'b') # 'a: b'
```

Both these methods are relatively intuitive and you can Google "string formatting Python" if you want to know more.

Now, let's look at the `print(end='...')` part of the statement. The `print` function takes an argument called `end` which specifies the string to be printed after whatever else you printed. The default value is `end='\n'`. This produces natural behavior if you call `print` a few times in a row as each thing will be printed on a new line.

```
print('a')
print('b')
print('c')

# a
# b
# c
```

However, if you want to print multiple things that *are not* separated by new lines, you can provide the function and argument for `end`.

```
print('a', end=', ')
print('b', end=', ')
print('c', end='...\n')
print('There we go!')

# a, b, c...
# There we go!
```